# WAMP show logs in realtime in console

Tags: wampserver

I'am using the WAMPServer, and it's located in `d:/wamp/`. Is there a way to show logging window or console in realtime as I'am crawling on my server web ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On unix/linux boxes I tend to use the `tail` command to watch logs as I browse for debugging. Of course, Windows has no equivalent, but there are a few options. The one I settled with was `mTAIL`. It's a standalone app and not a command line program, but it does exactly what you'd expect:

[image: mTAIL at work]

I was going to suggest using `unxtools`, a suite of ported GNU tools that can be used on the command line, but it's out of date and trying it on more recent versions of Windows I had problems. You can [download them from sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/) if you want to take a look. Also [tail for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tailforwin32/), is another Windows app that unfortunately doesn't seem to work on later versions, but included here in case it saves anyone the time looking.

Of course, you may find that if you prefer the command line you want to look at [getting cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) installed, which contains a host of commands you could use for the task you have.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions Leo. I really prefer command line, especially if there is something available for the cygwin. Could you tell me pls, under which keywords could I find the tools for cygwin ? I'am not a quite sure which keywords to type for that term.

Comment: And for the record, I prefer command line too :) I'm stuck on Windows myself, I feel your pain ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Follow with PowerShell

The PowerShell command to follow a file is `Get-Content -Wait` <*filepath*>

## Settings

I've added these settings to the Windows Terminal settings.json

```json
{
   "commandline": "%SystemRoot%\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -c \"Get-Content -Wait c:\\wamp\\logs\\php_error.log",
   "font": 
   {
      "cellHeight": "1.1",
      "face": "Cascadia Mono",
      "size": 7.0
   },

   "name": "Follow php_error",
   "padding": "8, 8, 8, 8",
   "snapOnInput": true,
   "startingDirectory": "c:\\wamp"
}
```

Why a small font? because Windows Terminal wraps long lines and [will not change to do so](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1860) in the near future